# Power Apps saving and accessing data between users without Premium

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-canvas

We are building an application in Power Apps in which we have option to save the user entered data and show it to other people. We have used SQL database for storing data and connecting using PowerAutomate. Now the app is ready and for deploying in organisation level it's asking for Premium license. Is it possible to store to access and store data in PowerApps application without Power Apps premium license? I have tried using REST API, Custom connectors, SQL Database which all are under Premium.

Please let me know is there any possibility to build the application which can be used organisation with Basic/Free license.

Answer (score 0):

You can't work with the conecters mentioned without Premium Licence. But you have the option to insert data into Sharepoint List for then with a Flow, that it can't linked with Powerapps, insert that data to SQL. This practice is not recomenden because Microsoft can penalize you.